# Spring+Hibernate+SQLite transaction oddities

Tags: spring, hibernate, sqlite, jpa, transactions

I have a problem with rollback failed transactions in Spring + Hibernate + SQLite stack.

Here is main classes of my example

- **Annotation Application Config** http://pastebin.com/XbejGHft
- **TestBean** http://pastebin.com/3BSFy34p
- **Order** entity - POJO with two fields (id and name)

Looks at the method TestBean.testMethod()

```
public void testMethod()    {
    entityManager.persist(createOrder("1"));
    entityManager.persist(createOrder("2"));
    entityManager.persist(createOrder("3"));
    entityManager.createQuery("from Order").getResultList();
    entityManager.persist(createOrder("4"));
    throw new RuntimeException("Managed");
}
```

It creates and persists some Order entities.
Between some creations it reads some data from database.
At the end it throws RuntimeException to simulate failure during method invocation and force Spring to rollback transaction.

After execution I open database and see, that it is completley rollback only last created entity (createOrder("4")) and all other (with names "1", "2" and "3") still present in the database. But since TestBean is marked as @Transactional then it should remove all four entities created in one transactional method testMethod().

I tried all journal_mode in the SQLIte but rollback still not worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that Hibernate call **JdbcIsolationDelegate#delegateWork** on each **em.persist()** invocation. At the same time, method **JdbcIsolationDelegate#delegateWork** calls **Connection#commit** which brokes all transactional interaction in JPA/Hibernate frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long I found true cause of the problem - it is strategy type of the `@GeneratedValue` annotation of the all entities in the application.

By default the annotation provides strategy is `AUTO`, and it means that Hibernate will use its own table in the target database (`hibernate_sequence`) for generating ID values. Hibernate invokes query in the separate transaction (selection of the  current value from hibernate_sequence) - and in this point we faced with the problem.

If you use generic multi connection data source than Hibernate tries to obtain new connection, but SQLite can have only one active connection - we gain the "database file is locked" error.
If you use Spring's `SingleConnectionDataSource` which prevents connection closing, then Hibernate will reuse the existing connection, but will create new separate transaction. New transaction will be completed successfully, but old transaction which asked for new ID will be failed.

So solution is very simple, just make sure that **all** your entities annotated like that

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

So, in this case Hibernate will delegate generating of the ID values to the underlying database.

Comment: Seems I got burned by this also trying to get Spring Boot to work with sqlite3: I kept getting "database is locked" exception inside a @Transactional annotation because of this - I was using GenerationType.SEQUENCE and Hibernate was trying to manage sequence generation while also creating new entities. As soon as I switched to GenerationType.IDENTITY it worked.